# How to check if the user is new registered user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working on android application which works as expected , but I'm using FirebaseUI to authenticate users login , I'm using this code for authentication and registration :

```
startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance()
                                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                    .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                                    .setAvailableProviders(Arrays.asList(
                                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build(),
                                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build()))
                                    .build(),
                            RC_SIGN_IN);
```

Is there any way to know if the current user is new user after login using `onActivityResult()`

Comment: are you writing the user to the database? if not, cloud functions has a `onCreate` trigger for whenever a new user is created, you could use that

Comment: The way I did was I just passed boolean value to the database to determine if the user is new or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cloud functions like this:

```
exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.auth.user().onCreate((event) => {
   // ...
 });
```

this function will trigger everytime a new user is created.

It will trigger when the following occurs:

1. A user creates an email account and password.
2. A user signs in for the first time using a federated identity provider.
3. The developer creates an account using the Firebase Admin SDK.
4. A user signs in to a new anonymous auth session for the first time.

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events

Answer (score 1):

It is explained in the repo:
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth#user-metadata

The easiest way is to compare last sign in time to the creation time on the user to determine if the user is new or existing.